# Is this the correct way to wrap readFileSync in a Promise

Tags: javascript

The reason for the below code is to get rid of `callback hell`/`pyramid of doom`. I don't fully understand `i/o blocking` though yet.

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var co = require('co');

co(function* () {

    var fileName = 'readme.txt';

    var str =
        yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var result;
            try {
                result = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    console.log('result readFileSync: ' + str);

});
```

All I'm expecting is a `yes` or `no` answer to be honest. Hope fully if no could someone give some details as I'm trying to learn properly about JavaScript sync/async and how to harness the power of Promises.

Comment: Why in the world would you try to wrap a promise around `rs.readFileSync()`?  If you want async, use `fs.readFile()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ever heard of `callback hell`/`pyramid of doom`? Go check it!

Comment: @KarlMorrison - Where is your callback function?

Comment: `fs.readFileSync` does not need callbacks at all.  It's synchronous.  There is no callback hell with `fs.readfileSync()`. I'm thinking that maybe you meant to ask about `fs.readFile()` which IS asynchronous and does involve callbacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer

No

### Useful answer

If you want to wrap a file read operation, try to use the async versions of Node functions as much as possible. Using `readFileSync` with a promise gives you no advantage over using `readFileSync` on its own, because `readFileSync` blocks the process until it is done reading, which `readFile` does not.

A better solution would therefore be something like this:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

var readFilePromise = function(file) {
  return new Promise(function(ok, notOk) {
    fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          notOk(err)
        } else {
          ok(data)
        }
    })
  })
}

readFilePromise('/etc/passwd').then(function(data) {
  // do something with the data...
})
```

Comment: 1 up also, One of the better answers I have received!

Comment: Down voting this because it is not the correct way.

Comment: @dman Promisify was added in Node 8.0.0 (source: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), which was released   2017-05-30 (source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), I posted this answer in 2016. I think it's interesting to have your answer in mind for Node 8+. But for anything 8-, my answer seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way is to use the Node's *native* util library and promisfy `fs.readFile`:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'index.html');
const readFile = require('util').promisify(fs.readFile);

readFile(INDEX)
  .then(e => console.log(e.toString()))
  .catch(e => console.log('FOOBAR ' + e));
```

---

result:

```
one@dolphin:~/github/resume $ node toolchain/inject.js 
FOOBAR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/one/github/resume/toolchain/app/index.html'
```

Comment: Isn't promisfying with util just the same as wrapping it in a Promise?

Comment: @KarlMorrison yes, but you asked the `correct` way. Methodology trumps all else. The same with array methods, you use them over loops. 


Outside the context of a promise and on a side note: We took ~13 lines and made them into one line. This is acceptable because `utils` is a native library and does not bloat  the code base.  It would be unacceptable to make 13 lines of code  into 1 if it was done with a library that was not native, such as lodash, which would bloat the codebase.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I agree with you, was just curious if anythnig else was in play here :)

Comment: @KarlMorrison You can read more in the Node Util docs. Were you going to accept this as the answer or at the least upvote?

Comment: You will certainly indeed get an upvote! :) conradkdotcom however did explain the essentials behind the sync vs. async approach process approaches, meaning that readFileSync and readFile should be used in different scenarios and cannot replace each other even when promisifyed.